# Change method font color back to what it was (from Android Studio Update)

Tags: android, android-studio, text, editor

After updating Android studio, my text color changed to a dark black for all methods like in the image below. I can't find the settings to change it in File>Settings>Editor. I just want a color that is light so I can see it clearer.

[image: 1]

Comment: post an image of your currant status

Comment: @Charuka done, sorry it seems that my link didn't work

Comment: ok great its seems like you have a different theme , so you want to keep it and change the text color only or change everything to default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download new themes from https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes as your preference

Once you have downloaded the `.jar` file, go to File -> Import Settings... and choose the file downloaded.

Set a one you like using File->Settings->Editor->Colors & Fonts-> Select a default one or a new one

Answer (score 0):

Go to `File->Settings->Editor->Colors & Fonts->`

Then select **Darcula** and apply. You'll get nice dark background theme editor.

*or*

You can download new themes from https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes and then go to `File -> Import Settings` and choose the downloaded file.